# Arduino mini pro as ISP for Atmega329P-PU serial monitor failing

Tags: serial, atmega328, arduino-pro-mini

After trying a lot of tutorials and manuals around the web including at least 20 solutions here on StackExchange, I don't know what to try anymore.

My goal is to write a message in the serial monitor window of the Arduino IDE from my ATMEGA328P-PU.

[image]

I have written the Arduino bootloader (tried 8 and 16MHz) to the ATMEGA and I use a 'blink' sketch as follows:

```
void setup()  {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 delay(100);
 pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
 digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
 Serial.print("high");
 delay(1000);
 digitalWrite(9, LOW);
 Serial.print("low");
 delay(1000);
}
```

The blinking works fine, the timing looks good, not overly fast or slow.

I connect PIN3 (PCINT17, PD1, TXD) directly to the RX on the Arduino (lower red wire) and the serial monitor responds by returning nonsense like `����������`.

I have checked the baud rate. I have also tested with all other baud rates in combination with and without 8Mhz and 16MHz.

I have tested the entire setup with another ATMEGA328P-PU and using an entirely other PC. Same results.

It is not possible to upload a sketch while leaving the TXD -> RX connected, so I disconnect this cable when I upload a sketch. I have also tested with only power and TXD -> RX connected.

I have also tried a few types of resistor between the TXD and RX, one of many tutorials recommended this.

This is what I am trying:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Attiny-serial-monitor-using-arduino-walkthrough/

And this is my boards.txt:

```
##############################################################

atmega328bb.name=ATmega328 (8 MHz internal clock)

atmega328bb.upload.protocol=arduino
atmega328bb.upload.maximum_size=30720
atmega328bb.upload.speed=57600

atmega328bb.bootloader.low_fuses=0xE2
atmega328bb.bootloader.high_fuses=0xDA
atmega328bb.bootloader.extended_fuses=0x05

atmega328bb.bootloader.file=atmega/ATmegaBOOT_168_atmega328.hex
atmega328bb.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
atmega328bb.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F

atmega328bb.build.mcu=atmega328p
atmega328bb.build.f_cpu=16000000L
atmega328bb.build.core=arduino:arduino
atmega328bb.build.variant=arduino:standard


atmega328bb.bootloader.tool=arduino:avrdude
atmega328bb.upload.tool=arduino:avrdude
```

Comment: The problem is most likely that big white component. Yes, that one. The breadboard. It has huge parasitic capacitance and will be affecting the frequency of your crystal oscillations, thus skewing your baud rate enough to break communication.

Comment: I have tried without external oscillator..

Comment: So you have arduino pro mini as ISP and you've connected TX pin from mega328p to pro mini RX input (which is also connected to USB->Serial TX pin). And you wonder why it returns junk data from pro mini Tx pin?

Comment: Speaking of capacitance, I don't see any decoupling on that ATMega328 chip...

Comment: yes I wonder why it returns this, that is why I post a question here.

Comment: Well, you have Arduino ISP on that arduino mini pro and if you connect output of bare chip to input of that arduino then Arduino ISP is confused and sends (possibly) some responses to its RXO pin (connected to TX Input on USB-Serial board).

Comment: Is ArduinoISP not supposed to forward this information to the Arduino IDE? How else would I read serial messages from the bare chip?

Comment: I don't think so. Even if it does, it's possibly running at much higher baud rate. And if there are no resistors on that USB-Serial you have shorted two outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see at image from linked instructables, they've connected `TX` pin from Tiny to `TX` pin on `UNO` through `220R` resistor. This is extremely lousy idea as `UNO` and `Tiny` are both driving `TX` pins.

On the other side you've connected `TX` Output pin from `Target CPU` into `RX` Input of the `Arduino ISP (pro mini)`. `Arduino ISP` returns some error responses from its `TXO` pin directly into the monitor. And it's at different speed I suppose, as default baud rate is `19200` in `Arduino ISP` sketch.

Also using internal `8MHz` oscillator and: `atmega328bb.build.f_cpu=16000000L` means you are running at half speed as compiler and everything else expects. All speeds will be at half rate. Delays twice as long and so on.

Anyway, you can disconnect your USB to Serial converter and connect it directly to the target CPU. Or use two of them. Or just upload bootloader and get rid of ISP.

Comment: great, just wiring the FTDI to the ATMEGA gives me normal serial monitor response. it does leave me with another challenge, uploading sketches does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you have 2 ATmegas for 1 uploader. You can't really remove the ATmega on the Pro Mini so I suggest removing the ATmega of an UNO and using the UNO without the ATmega to program your seperate ATmega. Tx to Rx and vice versa. 16MHz will work.

Comment: No change of boards is needed, it is only necessary to hold the on-board ATmega in reset, and bring the raw DTR or RTS line over to a copy of the reset circuit for the target one.  However, if loading anything that uses SPI or toggles those pins it would generally be good to make sure the ISP (SPI) lines are disconnected between the two, to make sure the slave doesn't accidentally deprogram the on-board ATmega (seen that happen!)

Comment: So how's my anwser?

Comment: Not very good, as you are proposing that an unnecessary purchase of different hardware be made.